# Admin Check Script Not Working

Tags: php, session, admin

so i have done this script below to check if logged in user is not admin and redirect non-admin to 404 page, but keep admin in the same page and show him his stuff

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $loggedin = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
    if ($username != "administrator") {
        header("location: 404.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        include 'include/usermenu.php';
    }
?>
```

but my admin is also redirected to 404(he shouldn't be), so could anybody tell me what have i done wrong? and by the way im having just one admin, so thats why its username

Comment: `var_dump` `$_SESSION['username'];` and post it. Or maybe you would even figure it out yourself, without posting.

Comment: no its not about checking username, and username is allright because i tried echoing it. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test, change your code as follows:

```
<?php  
 session_start();  
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];  
 $loggedin = $_SESSION['loggedin']; 
 if ($username != "administrator") {
   ##header("location: 404.php"); exit;
   print "normally I would redirect you because username is $username ";
 } else {
   include 'include/usermenu.php'; 
 }
?>
```

See if username is coming up as a blank or some alternate spelling?